# String to Date Conversion Error Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, date, parsing

I cannot for the life of me get the date comparison to work in this script. I've tried Date.strpTime, Date.parse, to_date, and my most recent attempt, convert the string to an integer then create a new date from it, and with every attempt, I'm receiving "invalid date" errors. I'm using Ruby 2.2.3. Any assistance with how I might get the date parsed correctly would be greatly appreciated.

```
require 'date'

def exec_script

fpAcct = {
'001xxxxxxxxxxx1' => '1-1-1980',
'001xxxxxxxxxxx2' => '1-1-1980',
'001xxxxxxxxxxx3' => '1-1-1980',
'001xxxxxxxxxxx4' => '1-1-1980',
'001xxxxxxxxxxx5' => '1-1-1980',
'001xxxxxxxxxxx6' => '1-1-1980' 
}

CSV.open( "afile4.csv", 'w' ) do |writer|
  fpAcct.each_key do |acct|
      newDate = Date.new(1980,1,1);
      ACCTTOOPPDATE.each_key do |ct|
        components = ACCTTOOPPDATE[ct].slice(21..-1).split('-')
        components2 = fpAcct[acct].split('-')
        goodDate = Date.new(components[2].to_i, components[1].to_i, components[0].to_i)
        goodDate2 = Date.new(components2[2].to_i, components2[1].to_i, components2[0].to_i)

        if acct == ACCTTOOPPDATE[ct].slice(0..17) && goodDate2 < goodDate
          newDate = goodDate
        end
      end

     fpAcct[acct] = newDate
     writer << [acct, fpAcct[acct]]
     end
  end
end

ACCTTOOPPDATE = {
'001xxxxxxxxxxxa' => '001xxxxxxxxxxxx1 + 8-28-2015',
'001xxxxxxxxxxxb' => '001xxxxxxxxxxxx2 + 1-7-2015',
'001xxxxxxxxxxxc' => '001xxxxxxxxxxxx3 + 1-8-2015',
'001xxxxxxxxxxxd'' => '001xxxxxxxxxxxx4 + 1-8-2015',
'001xxxxxxxxxxxe' => '001xxxxxxxxxxxx5 + 8-4-2014'
}

exec_script
```

Note: If I comment out the Date.new assignment statements section of the code and replace it with...

```
puts components[2].to_i
puts components[1].to_i
puts components[0].to_i
puts
puts components2[2].to_i
puts components2[1].to_i
puts components2[0].to_i
```

I get (for one of the loop iterations as an example) :

```
2015
10
7

1980
1
1
```

So I know I'm grabbing the right section of the string in my string manipulation statements. I'm just not sure why I can't create a date from it, and in general why I can't parse that string by the other standard means to get a date in the first place.

***UPDATE:

(After getting help on resolving the Date issue, I noticed a major logic flaw and fixed it, so I figured I'd update that here as well):

```
CSV.open( "afile4.csv", 'w' ) do |writer|
  fpAcct.each_key do |acct|
    newDate = Date.strptime(fpAcct[acct], "%m-%d-%Y")
      ACCTTOOPPDATE.each_key do |ct|
        components = (ACCTTOOPPDATE[ct].match(/\+ (.*)/))[1]
        goodDate = Date.strptime(components, "%m-%d-%Y")

        if acct == ACCTTOOPPDATE[ct].slice(0..17) && goodDate > newDate
           newDate = goodDate
        end
      end
    writer << [acct, newDate]
end
```

end
end

Comment: Just an comment, it's idiomatic in Ruby to use snake case instead of camel case: `new_date` vs `newDate`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you change this:

```
components = ACCTTOOPPDATE[ct].slice(21..-1).split('-')
```

To:

```
components = ACCTOOPPDATE[ct].match(/\+ (.*)/)[1]
```

Now we have the string `"8-28-2015"` stored in `components`.

You're right that `Date.parse` or `Date.new` does not like the MM-DD-YYYY format.  We can use [Date#strptime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime) though to get a date object.  `Date#strptime` let's us tell the parser what format the string is in.

```
Date.strptime("8-28-2015", "%m-%d-%Y")
=> #<Date: 2015-08-28 ((2457263j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Comment: I'm receiving the error "undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass" when I change it to that. If I delete the [1] at the end, I get "no implicit conversion of MatchData into String" - any idea why it doesn't like that last part of the syntax?

Comment: Never mind! I got it (with your recommendation). Thank you so much! I'm sorry I can't up vote your answer. I don't have enough reputation to vote yet :(